# How can I create a list of all paragraphs?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I would like the generate a list of all paragraph headings in my document that would result in something like the following.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\paragraph{Foo}

\paragraph{Bar}

\paragraph{Baz}

...

\chapter{Summary}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
    \item Baz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you make your example more complete? do you have sections, subsections,...?

Comment: Are your paragraphs numbered within the document, or are you just interested in their titles?

Comment: @Werner Paragraphs are not numbered within the document. I only would like to list their titles.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using a ToC elsewhere in your document, you can process it to achieve what you want. The example below processes the ToC in search of entries that are specific to `paragraph`, and setting only their titles (ignoring the page number) as part of an `enumerate` list.

To avoid issues with an empty list, an `\item` is set if there are no `\paragraph`s in your document, or the ToC hasn't been written.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}% Add paragraphs to ToC

\newcommand{\printparagraphtitles}{%
  \section{Summary}
  \begin{enumerate}
    % Update the way \contentsline works in order to capture on paragraphs
    \renewcommand{\contentsline}[3]{%
      \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{##1}{paragraph}=0
        \item ##2
      \fi
    }
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.toc}{}{}% Insert the regular ToC
    \ifnum\value{enumi}=0 \item\fi% If you don't have any paragraphs
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Foo}

\paragraph{Bar}

\paragraph{Baz}

\printparagraphtitles

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 to point that paragraphs could be in the regular ToC with  `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`. Sadly, I can't upvote more for the magic part.

Comment: The macro do not work if there are several sections or  subsections. It could be better if `\printparagraphtitles` show a global list, ignoring all the document structure, or conversely, show only a local list for the actual section, subsubsection or subsubsections, like a minitoc. Although it seem a work for a package more than for an answer!.